# Removing element of list based on predicate

Tags: python, list, predicate

What is the best (as in conventional) way to remove all elements of a list that satisfy a predicate? The function removep that I have should take in list lst and predicate pred and return the lst minus any elements that satisfied pred. This is what I have so far:

```
def removep(lst, pred):
    for element in lst:
        if pred(element):
            lst.pop(element.index)
    return lst
```

Comment: `filter(pred, list)`

Comment: Wouldn't `list(filter(pred, lst))` put all elements that satisfy the pred into a new string? How would I make a filter for all elements that don't satisfy pred?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. `filter(lambda x: not pred(x), lst)` or `itertools.filterfalse(pred, lst)` would work.